# WebBrowser Control | Mutliple iFrame Embedded YTPLAYER Vids | Only 1st Vid Functions

Tags: internet-explorer, video, iframe, vb6, webbrowser-control

In a VB6 application:

- If I load a HTML page with multiple ytplayer iFrame embeds only the first video functions. The other iFrame videos below it appear as white boxes.
- If I load the exact same HTML page in Internet Explorer all of the videos function.

I'm trying to figure out which setting I need to tweak. I've been pouring over the [FeatureControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330720(v=vs.85)) but haven't spotted anything.

Any ideas where else to look for this setting or group of settings?

Here is a sample of a HTML file which loads properly in Internet Explorer but does not load properly in the webbrowser control:

[Sample HTML File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6oagnyfvwa5sjex/Sample.htm?dl=0)

TKS

Comment: Are you using [jquery.mb.YTPlayer](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer)? Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue so that we can have a test and see how to help. Thanks for your understanding. With only the above description, we can't locate the issue.

Comment: Thanks - I've added a sample HTML file to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using WebBrowser in VB.NET to display the page? If so, I think the issue might be caused by that WebBrowser in VB.NET doesn't use IE 11 by default. I try to add this line in the first line of **Sample.htm** `<head>`, then it can work with WebBrowser in VB.NET:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

The result is like below:

[image]

Comment: Did the above not work if you excluded that meta tag?  Adding that tag did not fix the problem for me.  I thought it might be because you're running off a local server, so I set one up and tried that but it still fails.  I think it must be some async script setting ...

Comment: Odd that the first frame works and then it quits.

Comment: No, it doesn't work without that meta tag. I test with serving your Sample.htm on localhost and load the page in a WebBrowser control. You can also try these steps on other machines to see if the issue still exists and if there're other codes which may influence the result.